# How to specify types for overloaded function with multiple return types?

Tags: typescript, overloading, union-types

The following TypeScript code will not compile:

```
interface ZeroFunc {
    (value: string): string;
    (value: number): number;
}

const zero: ZeroFunc = (value: string | number) =>
    typeof value === 'string' ? '' : 0;
```

The error:

```
Type '(value: string | number) => "" | 0' is not assignable to type 'ZeroFunc'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)
```

It seems to be complaining about the return type.

The error makes sense, even though the function is implemented correctly.

Is there a way to correctly specify the type of this function, *without* using `any` as the return type?

Is it possible at all to implement the `ZeroFunc` interface correctly?

### Edit:

Here's a better illustration of the problem:

```
function zero(value: string): string;
function zero(value: number): number;
function zero(value: string | number): string | number {
    return typeof value === 'string' ? '' : 0;
}

type ZeroFunc = typeof zero;

const zero2: ZeroFunc = (value: string | number): string | number {
    return typeof value === 'string' ? '' : 0;
}
```

The declaration of `zero2` has the same error as above. But clearly, they're the exact same function signatures. I literally just copy-pasted it.

The type `ZeroFunc` even has the exact same definition as my interface above.

Comment: Just add third overload which will accept and return union of string and number

Comment: @captain-yossarian That doesn't work, the return type would need to be `string & number` in that case. It seems like this is just impossible to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is going to be an error unless this proposal gets implemented: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34319

Having function `implements` would essentially solve this issue.

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37824

In particular, from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37824#issuecomment-611696644):

> [...] in #6075 we added a special bivariance check between return types of overloads and implementations. It's an unsound laxness, but it allowed people to model these cases more easily.
>
> We didn't add this check for the general case of checking assignability between a function to a type with overloads because it wasn't clear if the intent was going to be the same.

In other words, the example with plain `function` really shouldn't compile either, but it was allowed because otherwise things would just be way too annoying.

For function assignments, it wasn't allowed, because it would be way easier to break things, and the benefits didn't outweigh the risks.

Comment: Thanks @Apples it worked for me. Adding `any` to the return type feels weird but at least the types works

Answer (score 0):

ZeroFunc interface has two methods which doesn't match the right-hand side of your final assignment (a function that takes string or number and returns string or number).

I guess I would do it like so:

```
interface ZeroFunc {
  (value: string | number): string | number;
}

const zero: ZeroFunc = (value: string | number) => typeof value === 'string' ? '' : 0;
```

But then I wonder why the interface is necessary. What are you trying to enforce?

**UPDATE**:

> I'm trying to enforce that if the parameter is a number, then the return type will be number. And for a string parameter, the return type is string.

I wondered if it were possible as follows:

```
type ZeroFunc<T> = (value: T) => T;

// OK
const zeroString: ZeroFunc<string> = (value: string) => '';
// OK
const zeroNumber: ZeroFunc<number> = (value: number) => 0;

// Bad case caught: 
//   Type '(value: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'ZeroFunc<number>'.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
const zeroBad: ZeroFunc<number> = (value: number) => '';

// But this is also bad and is NOT caught
const zero: ZeroFunc<string | number> = (value: string | number) => 0;
```

But seems not - the last case compiles because the return value matches the type `string | number`.

Comment: I'm trying to enforce that if the parameter is a number, then the return type will be number. And for a string parameter, the return type is string. A number parameter will never result in a string, and vice versa.